# STL lists to call function of a class

Tags: c++

i am trying to create a list that stores 10 objects. and then use the list to call functions from my class.
here is the code showing what i have tried.

```cpp
class numbers {
private:
  int indexCount;

public:
  int randomize(int arr[], int n) {
    indexCount = 0;

    for (int i = n - 1; i > 0; i--) {
      int j = rand() % (i + 1);
      indexCount++;
      swap(&arr[i], &arr[j]);
    }
  }

  void printArray(int arr[], int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
      cout << arr[i] << " ";

    cout << "random calls: " << indexCount << endl;
  }
};

int main() {

  srand(time(NULL));

  list<numbers> list1;
  int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 0, 0};
  int n = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
  numbers num[10];

  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    list1.push_back(num[i]);
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    list1[i].randomize(arr, n);
    list1[i].printArray(arr, n);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

in particular if i change this line

```
list <numbers> list1;
```

to

```
vector <numbers> list1;
```

the code works fine.
currently i am getting this error

> no match for operator[](types are list and int

still new to learning lists as well.

EDIT: this is as a uni task, i am aware that using rand() is not efficient and there are other ways however my code is following the task requirement.

Comment: `no match for operator[](types are list and int` - is this the whole error message? `swap(&arr[i], &arr[j]);` - you want to swap pointers to int?

Comment: I c++ you should avoid the use of c style arrays (`int arr[]`)  use std containers like `vector` instead. `int n = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);` is also a construct you would avoid in c++, if you change `arr` to a std container like `vector` you can call `size` on it to get the number of elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

And `std::list` does not support random access (`operator[]`).

You need to iterate over the list using iterators, by e.g. using a range-base loop:

```
  for (auto &item : list1) {
    item.randomize(arr, n);
    item.printArray(arr, n);
  }
```